# What is the difference between a private CA and self-signed certs?

Tags: ssl

I understand a "public CA" is something like Let's Encrypt. They are for the public and browsers.

Let's say I use this library CloudFlare SSL to create a CA for a closed group of people: https://github.com/cloudflare/cfssl

I assume I just created a "private CA". Now if I use this CA to generate some certs, are these certs "self-signed"?

Comment: depends on the root CA certificate you are using with this CA ... if the root cert is self-signed then all certs signed by this root cert are self-signed too, but you can also buy a root cert from a public CA

Comment: No, they are not self-signed, they are signed by your private CA.

Comment: @Pali+ In the X.509/PKIX world, 'self-signed' is a technical term and does not mean (just) signed by me myself or you yourself, it means a cert signed using the _same keypair_ as contained in the cert, i.e. it is _every_ root cert and _only_ those. Other certs signed by a private CA are private CA certs, but are not self-signed. However, many people and websites blogs etc. get this wrong, so be prepared to see it misused, although that CF page on a quick scan looks right. BTW browsers (and apps and other things) _can_ accept private CAs, they just don't do so by default.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 you are right, can you also post your comment as answer?